# How to write intermediate solutions as output in Minizic comand line?

Tags: minizinc

I have been running Minizinc models  from the command line, and I get final solutions as output.
I know I can make Minizic print intermedite solutions in the IDE. How can I make the same from the command line, so that they are printed as output like in the IDE?  Btw, I'm refering to the output Minizinc prints by default, not to the 'output' (the one that acts like print) that you can include in the code of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output intermediate solutions you can use the `-a` flag on optimisation problems. So for example `minizinc --solver gecode -a model.mzn data.dzn` will solve `model.mzn` with `data.dzn` on the Gecode solver and output all intermediate solutions.

Note, however, that the `-a` flag has has a few peculiarities:

- `-a` for satisfiability will output **all solutions** instead of intermediate solutions. So while scripting you need to be careful.
- Not all solvers support the `-a` flag. Not all solver will have (or output) intermediate solution.

Comment: Do geceode, cplex and chuffed support it?

Comment: Yes, these solvers do support `-a`. You will likely find that most solvers will actually support this flag. It is however not something that MiniZinc forces solvers to do.

Comment: Is there a way for it to show the time when each intermediate solution was found?

Comment: Yes, you can just use the `--output-time` flag